# Adding an optional cost after choosing a shipping method

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, plugin

I'm trying to add an optional cost after the customer choose the GLS shipping method: he can choose to be notified by SMS about the status of his order paying a fixed cost. There's an existing plugin or Have you got suggestions on how to do so?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would think about skipping the costs, add it on all orders and offer free sms service.